# Preventing LFI with user input

Tags: php

I need a script to look for logs which are in separate files for each user so that I can get all the log data.

Right now I have something like this:

```
public function getLog($name)
{
    if (is_file($this->getFull($name)) && $this->isValidFile($name))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    // return false
}

public function getFull($name)
{
    return "/var/www/logs/" . $name . ".log";
}

public function isValidFile($accname)
{
    $allfiles = array_diff(scandir("/var/www/logs/" . $name . ".log"), array("..", "."));
    if (in_array($accname . ".log", $allfiles))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is that safe?

Comment: Where is $name comming from? Is it user input?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's coming from an input box in a form.

Comment: I could add trim() to the username too, to remove the nullbytes (if any), right?

Comment: Well, if I'm not missing something obvious I could just put in any user's name I want the log for and I would get it. That doesn't seem very safe to me (the context is somehow missing here (what you mean by safe), so I might be wrong).

Comment: No, that's right. I want to be able to get any usernames. But I want them to stay in that directory and not leave it by using arbitrary code (`../../../etc/passwd` (with nullbytes, maybe?)) etc.

EDIT: I know I'm appending .log but there's still other .log file around the fs they could maybe get to using arbitrary input.

Comment: Sorry, now I get it (I misinterpreted LFI). This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/908647/5136654

Answer (score 2):

Going from the above code, you need to be more concerned with [directory traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) than you do with LFI. Although similar, an LFI allows code execution of the traversed file while directory traversal allows file access.

To make safe, sanitize `"/var/www/logs/" . $name . ".log"` with the [`realpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function then check that the returned path begins with `/var/www/logs/`.

This will restrict the script so that only files ending in `.log` in the `logs` directory, or subdirectory thereof, can be accessed.

[PHP 5.6.3](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69353) fixed the last known issue with nulls terminating paths, so you shouldn't have that to worry about.

Comment: @Chris - you need to read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10. The attack that SilverlightFox describes is a basic path injection attack. The Top 10 document should help you finding those and other common flaws throughout your app.